# How to generate ppd file with foomatic in Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, printing, cups, ppd

I installed foomatic to try and find a PPD file for my HP OfficeJet J4680 printer. However it does not have one for my specific printer in its foomatic-ppdfile list. Is there a way to manually generate a PPD with foomatic for my specific printer or should I try another source such as Gutenprint or CUPS SDK? Or is there a PPD file that is close to what I have that would work?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing hplip, it should contain the driver for your printer.

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_j4680_series.html

Comment: You may also install hpijs for good measure. Both are in the fedora repos, so a `yum install` should do the trick.

Comment: Did that already on the first go round. It bombs out on a dependency (usblib) saying I don't have it installed when I do. and I'm not sure how to resolve that. I thought the foomatic approach would be easier.

Comment: I tried your link. Its actually a newer version than the one I tried however it also fails at libusb saying I don't have it it installed when I do.

Comment: It has got to be a bug in the hplip app. I just updated to libusb for FC22 and it still says libusb missing.

Comment: Its crazy how fickle Linux can be at times. After I updated LIbusb and restarted the PC, (and after the re-install of hplip failed due to "missing libusb") In CUPS web admin I was able to see my printer, add it, and print to it no problems. Weird...but in a good way..